# Press on link inside table with vba on webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, automation

I figured out how to navigate to the webpage and make it search for my specific input and so fourth. However when i get the list with the result i am not able to make vba click on it. I have tried different variations of:

```
objIE.document.getElementById("isc_ListGrid_1_body$28s").Click
```

But I'm unable to figure how to press the specifc cell (marked in blue in pic):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/giy27.jpg

I'm not getting any error's, but its not click on it either.

Comment: Can you provide the url or is it not public?#

Comment: I can't it is not public unfortunately. I can provide more of the code if needed?

Comment: Not quite sure how to extract all of the code, with it still being readable and not just in plain text. @QHarr

Answer (score 0):

You want the id of the table, not the id of the div. Then the last td within that table

e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector("td:last-child").Click
```

Try alternatively

```
Dim evt As Object
Set evt = ie.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "onclick", True, False

With ie.document.querySelector("td:last-child")
    .Focus
    .dispatchEvent evt
End With
```

Or

```
With ie.document.querySelector("td:last-child")
    .Focus
    .FireEvent "onclick"
End With
```

Comment: Last id is isc_1Mtable, and with your suggestion yields:

objIE.document.querySelector("td:isc_1Mtable").Click

which doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Neither does objIE.document.querySelector("isc_1Mtable").Click

Comment: Are you sure that is the right element as it is gives no indication in html of being clickable?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I am hovering over the right element. Is there any other way to make VBA click on it?

Comment: try other two options above in answer

Comment: No luck either.