# Excel VBA control of Internet Explorer Mouseover Drop Down

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I would appreciate some help with an Excel-based VBA tool. I'm trying to control a mouse-over dropdown menu in Internet Explorer, select a dropdown menu option, then fill input boxes with info from the Excel sheet.

I've tried several methods offered in other question threads, but I can't seem to get it to work. I don't have access to SendKeys

Here is what I have:

```
Public Sub SN_Submit()

Dim table as HTMLTable
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim objButton As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

IE.Navigate2 "http://internal_company_website"
IE.Visible = True

Do While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Loop

delay (1)

******Here is where the dropdown portion of the code goes*****
IE.document.getElementByID("PartNo").Value = "XX123"
IE.document.getElementByID("SerialNo").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")

delay (0.5)

IE.Document.GetElementByID("Display").Click
```

The dropdown menu element information is:
[Screenshot of Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqSBx.png)

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would reformat this in markdown so the code you have contributed is a bit clearer with `code`

Comment: From the above VBA script and the dropdown menu element, we don't know how the dropdown menu rendering and works, and not found the PartNo and SeriaNo elements. So, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the how the dropdown menu works as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you can FireEvent on mouse events or attach and dispatch an event. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56655037/6241235